# material error exporting model as .3ds used in opengl

Tags: materials, export

edit: I'm going to leave my original question in tact below this edit, but I can summarise now that the problem is losing datat when re-exporting a 3ds, I'm missing a whole material amongst other things. Does blender have a known export error?

I can take a 3ds model someone else has supplied me and it will load into opengl and opengl es with no problem. If I load that 3ds into blender and export as .3ds without changing anything I will get a material error when it gets displayed.

The error seems to be when drawing the same model multiple times, some instances of the model at random will either be completely white or completely black. The error will remain consistent for as long as the program lasts, next time the program loads then different models will have the error, there is no pattern to it.

Here is how the error looks if i load the same model in multiple times

https://imageshack.com/i/exJ6njx7p

If I load the same model and draw it multiple times, each instance will be all white, and will make other objects white, as though pure white light were eminating from it.

Comment: It's definitely a material export error, I just loaded the original models materials into the re-exported models materials at run time in code and the error was gone.

Comment: one of the issues was there is no specular exponent or shininess chunk in the 3ds file. this was what was causing all objects around to appear blindingly white as the program was defaulting to junk values, way above 1.0. This explains the random factor as the junk values would have varied.